# Cant upgrade Raspbian neither run Python

Tags: raspbian, python, software-installation, apt, update

I am trying to upgrade my Raspberry Pi 3 B+:

```
$ uname -a  
Linux plexmediaserver-pi 4.14.98-v7+ #1200 SMP Tue Feb 12 20:27:48 GMT 2019 armv7l GNU/Linux
```

But I am getting this weird error:

```
pi@plexmediaserver-pi:~ $ sudo apt update
Get:2 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-backports InRelease [91.8 kB]
Get:1 http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian stretch InRelease [25.4 kB]          
Get:3 http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian stretch InRelease [15.0 kB]           
Ign:4 https://downloads.plex.tv/repo/deb public InRelease    
Hit:5 https://downloads.plex.tv/repo/deb public Release
Err:2 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-backports InRelease
  Unknown error executing apt-key
Err:1 http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian stretch InRelease
  Unknown error executing apt-key
Err:3 http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian stretch InRelease
  Unknown error executing apt-key
Err:6 https://downloads.plex.tv/repo/deb public Release.gpg
  Unknown error executing apt-key
Reading package lists... Done
W: GPG error: http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-backports InRelease: Unknown error executing apt-key
E: The repository 'http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-backports InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: An error occurred during the signature verification. The repository is not updated and the previous index files will be used. GPG error: http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian stretch InRelease: Unknown error executing apt-key
W: An error occurred during the signature verification. The repository is not updated and the previous index files will be used. GPG error: http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian stretch InRelease: Unknown error executing apt-key
W: An error occurred during the signature verification. The repository is not updated and the previous index files will be used. GPG error: https://downloads.plex.tv/repo/deb public Release: Unknown error executing apt-key


root@plexmediaserver-pi:/home/pi# apt upgrade -y
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages will be upgraded:
  certbot libraspberrypi-bin libraspberrypi-dev libraspberrypi-doc libraspberrypi0 plexmediaserver python3-acme python3-certbot python3-josepy raspberrypi-bootloader raspberrypi-kernel
11 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 146 MB of archives.
After this operation, 6,475 kB disk space will be freed.
Get:1 http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian stretch/main armhf libraspberrypi-doc armhf 1.20190517-1 [31.4 MB]
Get:2 http://ftp.icm.edu.pl/pub/Linux/distributions/raspbian/raspbian stretch/main armhf python3-josepy all 1.1.0-2~deb9u1 [27.8 kB]
Get:3 http://ftp.icm.edu.pl/pub/Linux/distributions/raspbian/raspbian stretch/main armhf python3-acme all 0.28.0-1~deb9u1 [48.7 kB]
Get:4 http://ftp.icm.edu.pl/pub/Linux/distributions/raspbian/raspbian stretch/main armhf certbot all 0.28.0-1~deb9u2 [37.7 kB]
Get:6 https://downloads.plex.tv/repo/deb public/main armhf plexmediaserver armhf 1.15.6.1079-78232c603 [74.1 MB]
Get:5 http://ftp.icm.edu.pl/pub/Linux/distributions/raspbian/raspbian stretch/main armhf python3-certbot all 0.28.0-1~deb9u2 [222 kB]
Get:7 http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian stretch/main armhf libraspberrypi-dev armhf 1.20190517-1 [404 kB]                                                                                            
Get:8 http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian stretch/main armhf raspberrypi-kernel armhf 1.20190517-1 [35.1 MB]                                                                                           
Get:9 http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian stretch/main armhf libraspberrypi-bin armhf 1.20190517-1 [332 kB]                                                                                            
Get:10 http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian stretch/main armhf libraspberrypi0 armhf 1.20190517-1 [839 kB]                                                                                              
Get:11 http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian stretch/main armhf raspberrypi-bootloader armhf 1.20190517-1 [3,567 kB]                                                                                     
Fetched 146 MB in 53s (2,707 kB/s)                                                                                                                                                                       
Failed to import the site module
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/site.py", line 580, in <module>
    main()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/site.py", line 567, in main
    known_paths = addsitepackages(known_paths)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/site.py", line 344, in addsitepackages
    addsitedir(sitedir, known_paths)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/site.py", line 212, in addsitedir
    addpackage(sitedir, name, known_paths)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/site.py", line 168, in addpackage
    for n, line in enumerate(f):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/codecs.py", line 321, in decode
    (result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xbb in position 57: invalid start byte
Use of uninitialized value $value in substitution (s///) at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/Format/822.pm line 65, <__ANONIO__> line 51.
Use of uninitialized value $item in hash element at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/DbDriver/File.pm line 85, <__ANONIO__> chunk 54.
dpkg: error processing archive /tmp/apt-dpkg-install-t5lPVw/00-python3-josepy_1.1.0-2~deb9u1_all.deb (--unpack):
 subprocess dpkg-split returned error exit status 11
dpkg: error processing archive /tmp/apt-dpkg-install-t5lPVw/01-python3-acme_0.28.0-1~deb9u1_all.deb (--unpack):
 subprocess dpkg-split returned error exit status 11
dpkg: error processing archive /tmp/apt-dpkg-install-t5lPVw/02-certbot_0.28.0-1~deb9u2_all.deb (--unpack):
 subprocess dpkg-split returned error exit status 11
dpkg: error processing archive /tmp/apt-dpkg-install-t5lPVw/03-python3-certbot_0.28.0-1~deb9u2_all.deb (--unpack):
 subprocess dpkg-split returned error exit status 11
dpkg: error processing archive /tmp/apt-dpkg-install-t5lPVw/04-libraspberrypi-doc_1.20190517-1_armhf.deb (--unpack):
 subprocess dpkg-split returned error exit status 11
dpkg: error processing archive /tmp/apt-dpkg-install-t5lPVw/05-libraspberrypi-dev_1.20190517-1_armhf.deb (--unpack):
 subprocess dpkg-split returned error exit status 11
dpkg: error processing archive /tmp/apt-dpkg-install-t5lPVw/06-raspberrypi-kernel_1.20190517-1_armhf.deb (--unpack):
 subprocess dpkg-split returned error exit status 11
dpkg: error processing archive /tmp/apt-dpkg-install-t5lPVw/07-libraspberrypi-bin_1.20190517-1_armhf.deb (--unpack):
 subprocess dpkg-split returned error exit status 11
dpkg: error processing archive /tmp/apt-dpkg-install-t5lPVw/08-libraspberrypi0_1.20190517-1_armhf.deb (--unpack):
 subprocess dpkg-split returned error exit status 11
dpkg: error processing archive /tmp/apt-dpkg-install-t5lPVw/09-raspberrypi-bootloader_1.20190517-1_armhf.deb (--unpack):
 subprocess dpkg-split returned error exit status 11
dpkg: error processing archive /tmp/apt-dpkg-install-t5lPVw/10-plexmediaserver_1.15.6.1079-78232c603_armhf.deb (--unpack):
 subprocess dpkg-split returned error exit status 11
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /tmp/apt-dpkg-install-t5lPVw/00-python3-josepy_1.1.0-2~deb9u1_all.deb
 /tmp/apt-dpkg-install-t5lPVw/01-python3-acme_0.28.0-1~deb9u1_all.deb
 /tmp/apt-dpkg-install-t5lPVw/02-certbot_0.28.0-1~deb9u2_all.deb
 /tmp/apt-dpkg-install-t5lPVw/03-python3-certbot_0.28.0-1~deb9u2_all.deb
 /tmp/apt-dpkg-install-t5lPVw/04-libraspberrypi-doc_1.20190517-1_armhf.deb
 /tmp/apt-dpkg-install-t5lPVw/05-libraspberrypi-dev_1.20190517-1_armhf.deb
 /tmp/apt-dpkg-install-t5lPVw/06-raspberrypi-kernel_1.20190517-1_armhf.deb
 /tmp/apt-dpkg-install-t5lPVw/07-libraspberrypi-bin_1.20190517-1_armhf.deb
 /tmp/apt-dpkg-install-t5lPVw/08-libraspberrypi0_1.20190517-1_armhf.deb
 /tmp/apt-dpkg-install-t5lPVw/09-raspberrypi-bootloader_1.20190517-1_armhf.deb
 /tmp/apt-dpkg-install-t5lPVw/10-plexmediaserver_1.15.6.1079-78232c603_armhf.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
root@plexmediaserver-pi:/home/pi# python
Segmentation fault
```

It started when I tried to download subtitles with `subliminal`, but I've got this strange `Segmentation fault` error.
I've tried to uninstall, install, upgrade, remove... nothing is working. No python program is working. Some apt actions are not working as well.

Comment: Did you update first? The best option is to restore from your backup and try again.

Comment: Yes, I've issued `sudo apt update` first. I don't want to restore, because I don't have a backup. :(

Comment: Do you modified `/etc/apt/sources.list` and `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/raspi.list`? How do you install the plex mediaserver? I cannot find it in the default Raspbian repository. Please address me with @Ingo, otherwise I won't see your reply.